# Cannot install watchman from homebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, watchman

I just started developing apps using react native. When I tried to set up, I downloaded homebrew successfully, but I cant install watchman or node using the following command:

`brew install node`

`brew install watchman`

This is the result I have:

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "watchman".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core; brew update
```

I had same Issue recently this solved to me

Answer (score 0):

1. `brew doctor`
2. `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master`